# Call and run a code in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on sheet 1 that will run code code a created sheet, basically the program creates a new sheet, copy the code on the sheet 2 to this new sheet, run the code on this new sheet, display the final result on sheet 1 and delete this new sheet. But I having problems to run the code, is not running the code.

The new sheet has the name Calcs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calcs")

Call MySheet.Mycode

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it fall down? If you don't know step through the code and find the line that is causing the error. Can you post the `Mycode` sub as well

Comment: If that is your whole Sub for the `CommandButton2_Click`, you are not creating the worksheet prior to assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @Tom the error that appears is: This object doest support this property or method. Fall in this line Call MySheet.Mycode

Comment: @VictorMoraes is not just this part, the whole code is working, but I just posted a question in this part that is not working.

Comment: On which line? Step through the code. If your code isn't event triggered you shouldn't really store it in the worksheet (you get errors like the code not being found) and should instead store it in a module

Comment: Where do you "Copy the code" ? It doesn't appears in the sample you posted.

Comment: What does 'The whole code is working mean'? All you're doing here is calling the other procedure (and as has been stated, put it in a module), the declaration and set is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Mysheet does not contain any code when you are calling it.
If you are deleting the new sheet, you really have no purpose in storing the code in the new sheet. Why don't you store the code as public in a module?